# ¿Cómo contar las veces que se repite una columna en una consulta SELECT sin afectar la consulta resultante en MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Me he topado con este caso, espero y puedan ayudarme, quisiera saber si es posible reunir los datos en una sola consulta MYSQL pero sin afectar la consulta resultante, por ejemplo:

**Una tabla de estudiantes con los siguientes campos:**

**nombre**, **apellido**, **tipo**

**Datos:**
Juan, Arias, R1
Daniel, Garcia, R2
Pedro, Valencia, R4
Valeria, Muñóz, R2

La cuestión es saber cuantas veces el campo **'tipo'** se repite, es decir si yo realizo la consulta:

```
select * from estudiantes
```

Que trajera

```
nombre, apellido, tipo, R2, R1, R3
Juan,  Arias,     R1    2,  1,  1
Daniel,  Garcia,  R2,   2,  1,  1
Pedro,  Valencia, R3,   2,  1,  1
Valeria,  Muñóz,  R2,   2,  1,  1
```

Así de esta manera sabría que en la consulta que se realizó el tipo **R1** se repite 1 vez, el tipo **R2** se repite 2 veces y el tipo **R3** se repite 1 vez.

Pensé en hacer las sumas por items ya teniendo la consulta o desde jquery ya obteniendo los datos, pero el problema es que no se sabe cuantos tipos de estudiantes estarán en la bd, podrían ser desde **R1** hasta **R9** ó hasta **RN** y ahí me quita esa posibilidad.

Desde ya agradezco su contribución, espero su ayuda, gracias!

Comment: @Aprendiz creo que sí, sería cuestión de probarlo con el mío y hacer la adaptación  a ver que tal me va, gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: De nada considera que si lo aplicas y tienes problemas entonces puedes editarla agregando los detalles al respecto

Comment: Eso haré, una vez que tenga más detalles, gracias nuevamente!!

Comment: creo que solo necesitarías un select count(1) from tabla order by campo group_by campo

Comment: @FernandoUrban Lo he intentado de esa forma amigo pero no se si lo estoy haciendo mal, solo me devuelve las veces que se repite por fila, o sí los cuenta pero ya no me devuelve la consulta inicial sino solo el count() final.